# Is there in C API for PHP's CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER?

Tags: php, c, curl, libcurl

In PHP API we could  use `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);` but how to translate it into C? I tried `curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);` but failed.

Comment: The PHP source is in C, the curl extension is part of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` in libcurl C API. You can do that with a callback function, it's one of [libcurls examples](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html): [get a remote file in memory only](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html).

Answer (score 6):

I think this mailing list entry is relevant:

http://curl.haxx.se/mail/curlphp-2009-11/0005.html

> CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER was invented by the PHP binding author and is basically 
>   just a shortcut for appending all received data into a memory buffer. 
>   With the C API and basically all existing bindings as well (including the PHP 
>   one) you can use a write callback to append all data to a single buffer.